# JavaFX: Change scene using controllers

Tags: java, javafx, controller

I have a menu fxml and controller which contains a few possible options. Depending on the chosen button, the window will show a new list (eg. customer button shows a list of customers in a new scene). I just can't seem to figure out how to create the new scene by using controllers and fxmlLoaders.

I tried creating a new instance of CustomerController in the menu's personButtonHandle() method, but this gives an 'ignored new instance' warning.

Running the application works, but clicking the CustomerButton causes a "javafx.fxml.LoadException: Root value already specified."

**Main menu**

```
public Menu(DomainController dc) {
    this.dc = dc;

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().
            getResource("Main.fxml"));
    loader.setRoot(this);
    loader.setController(this);
    try {
        loader.load();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
private void handleBtnCustomers(ActionEvent event) {
        CustomerController cc = new CustomerController(this.dc);

}
```

**CustomerController**

```
public CustomerController(DomainController dc) {
        this.dc = dc;

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().
                getResource("Customers.fxml"));
        loader.setRoot(this);
        loader.setController(this);
        try {
            loader.load();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does your `.fxml`-file use the `<fx:root>`tag as root tag?

Comment: @Reizo removed that, still got the same problem

Comment: What exactly did you remove? Can you please add the fxml-file and the particular exception thrown?